# Primefaces AJAX Cannot render nested UIComponent AND actionListener is not working

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

## EDIT 2: Why it is different

@BalusC, this is different from [the post you say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo) because I'm asking about an `actionListener` weird behavior that's not executing a method.

Also, In my test I'm following the Primefaces's documentation, applying fixed `id` attribute to every `NamingContainer` and checking the generated HTML (and has the expected `id`'s)

The post you say it's a duplicate from this, was a good help but here we're talking about another problems.

---

I was working in a webapp's layout and found a problem updating the DOM. I'm working with **Primefaces 5.2** and **Glassfish 4.1**. To isolate the problem I tried to test it in other project but I found another issue in my test. Maybe I'm missing something, so I need to ask in this forum.

I'll go backwards: I'll describe the test and then the real problem so you can see it has the same structure

---

## THE FAILING TEST

#### index.xhtml

```
<h:body>
  <h:form id="form-render">
    <p:commandButton id="btnRender" value="Render" update=":form-rendered"
                     actionListener="#{renderView.setRender(true)}"/>
  </h:form>

  <h:form id="form-rendered">
    <h:outputText value="Rendered in form-rendered" rendered="#{renderView.render}"/>

    <p:panelGrid id="panel-grid" rendered="#{renderView.render}">
      <p:outputLabel value="Rendered in form-rendered:panel-grid"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

#### renderView.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RenderView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1687524798440117276L;
    private boolean render;

    public RenderView() {
        this.render = false;
        System.out.println("Constructor - render=" + this.render);
    }

    public boolean isRender() {
        return render;
    }

    public void setRender(boolean render) {
        this.render = render;
        System.out.println("Setter - render=" + this.render);
    }
}
```

But when I run the test only renders the `<h:outputText>` component. I tried another options:

- `update=":form-rendered, :form-rendered:panel-grid"`: same result
- `update=":form-rendered:panel-grid"`: doesn't render anything
- move `rendered=#{...}` attribute from `<p:panelGrid>` to `<p:outputLabel>` inside it: doesn't change

I don't know how to reference the `<p:panelGrid>` inside the `<h:form>`. According to [Primefaces's documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf):

> Update attribute takes a comma or white-space separated list of JSF component ids to be updated

So the first option should work, but it doesn't. What am I missing here?

---

## THE REAL PROBLEM

The previous test came from a problem I was facing working with a layout. The layout's idea is the following:

- In several pages I need to search something and show the results under the search form (with AJAX, of course).
- Every page in the layout is a `facelet template client` (made with `<ui:composition>`)
- This is ONLY the layout, there are not any queries, business logic or anything like that. The `@ManagedBean` classes I use are just creating dummy objects to populate the Primefaces's components

So I used the same structure of the previous test to solve the problem in every page. The funny thing is that I coded the first one and worked perfectly, but when I coded the second, fails on rendering the second form. **Even more, I coded the third and worked perfectly, coded the fourth and fails!!!**.

In my first solution attempt I used the following bean:

```
@ManagedBean // from javax.faces.bean
@ViewScoped  // idem
public class SearchView {
    private boolean showResults;

    public SearchView() {
        this.showResults = false;
        System.out.println("Constructor-showResults=" + this.showResults);
    }

    public boolean isShowResults() {
        return showResults;
    }

    public void setShowResults(boolean showResults) {
        this.showResults = showResults;
        System.out.println("Setter-showResults=" + this.showResults);
    }
}
```

I'll copy-paste from a working example first and then form a failing example, so maybe you can see something I'm missing.

#### searchPage1.xhtml (working)

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                template="./../templateMenu.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

  <ui:define name="left">
    <ui:include src="include/auMenu.xhtml"/>
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="content">
    <h1>Search 1</h1>

    <h:form id="form-busq-au">
      <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="ui-noborder">
        <!--form fields -->

        <p:commandButton value="Search" icon="ui-icon-search" style="width: 100%;"
                         actionListener="#{searchView.setShowResults(true)}"
                         update=":form-res-au"/>
      </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="form-res-au">
      <c:if test="#{searchView.showResults}">
        <h1>Search Results</h1>
      </c:if>
      <p:panelGrid id="panelgrid-res-au" columns="2" rendered="#{searchView.showResults}">
        <!-- other fields -->
      </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

#### searchPage2.xhtml (not working)

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                template="./../templateMenu.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

  <ui:define name="left">
    <ui:include src="include/menu.xhtml"/>
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="form-busq-mt">
      <h1>Search 2</h1>

      <p:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="ui-noborder">
        <!-- form fields -->
        <p:commandButton value="Search" icon="ui-icon-search" style="width: 100%;"
                         actionListener="#{searchView.setShowResults(true)}"
                         update=":form-res-mt"/>
      </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="form-res-mt">
      <c:if test="#{searchView.showResults}">
        <h1>Search Results</h1>
      </c:if>

      <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{searchView.showResults}">
        <!-- Other fields -->
      </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

As you can see, it's the same structure in the test and the two pages, but the behavior is different. I don't know if this is a bug in primefaces or what.

Debugging the code I realized that in the second page, the `setSearchResult(true)` method is never called, don't know why. So I tried the following solution:

### Failed solution attempt

Thinking that it was a problem with the `SearchView` Managed Bean, I made a change in the Controller: I made an abstract class with the attribute and methods and a `@ManagedBean` for each one of the web pages extending the abstract class. In code:

```
public abstract class SearchView {
    private boolean showResults;

    public SearchView() {
        this.showResults = false;
        System.out.println("Constructor-showResults=" + this.showResults);
        System.out.println("Class: " + this.getClass().toString());
        System.out.println("ID: " + this.getClass().hashCode());
    }

    public boolean isShowResults() {
        return showResults;
    }

    public void setShowResults(boolean showResults) {
        this.showResults = showResults;
        System.out.println("Setter-showResults=" + this.showResults);
    }
}
```

And for every search page:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ConcreteXXXSearchView extends SearchView implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4717041016001640528L;
}
```

but the result is the same (`setShowResult(true)` is never called in the second page). The `println()` methods in the `abstract class SearchView` was to test that I'm instantiating different objects (indeed, there are different).

I tried the test's options but the problem is in the `<p:commandButton>` because `actionListener` is not working.

## Summarizing

I'm facing two problems here:

- **In the test** I need to render a `<h:form>` containing a `UIComponent` that implements `NamingContainer`(`<p:panelGrid>`)
- **In the project** I need to know why the `setShowResults(true)` is not called in the failing page

Any help / guide is appreciated. Thanks in advance

## EDIT: more info

In both **TEST** and **REAL PROBLEM** I checked the *DOM* with the browser inspector and the `id` attribute is correct for both `<h:form id="form-res-mt">` and `<p:panelGrid id="panelgrid-res-mt">`

Comment: @BalusC, please watch my second edit, I think it's not a duplicate. I'm waiting for your comments. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have used `actionListener="#{searchView.setShowResults()}"` in your non-working approach.

```
<p:commandButton value="Search" icon="ui-icon-search" style="width: 100%;"
                         actionListener="#{searchView.setShowResults()}"
                         update="form-res-mt"/>
```

But, `searchView.setShowResults()` method expects a `boolean argument`, change your code to:

```
 <p:commandButton value="Search" icon="ui-icon-search" style="width: 100%;"
                             actionListener="#{searchView.setShowResults(true)}"
                             update="form-res-mt"/>
```

Also, use `<ui:fragment rendered="yourCondition">` instead of `<c:if test="condition">` **because if  component condition returns false ,it'll not attached to the component tree.** And thus  can't find the component in the UI Tree.

Comment: Maybe it was a copy/paste problem when I made a reduction for the post, NetBeans detects error calling the method. I checked what you're saying but it still doesn't work. Thank you as well for your time

Comment: Yes, i tried `<ui:fragment>` but the result is the same. In fact, if you deny the condition in `<c:if>` it is rendered when the `SearchView` Bean is intantiated (because `showResults` is initiated to `false` in the Constructor) The problem is in the `<p:commandButton>`'s `actionListener` attribute